# How do I get rid of the empty related pages tab in doxygen?

Tags: doxygen

When using markdown with doxygen, the documentation generates fine. However, I have one problem, which is that my documentation generates a related pages tab which is empty. For example, here is my main page:

```
# Project Name

Contents

This documentation is divided into the following sections:
- \subpage page_one
- \subpage page_two
```

And here is a sample subpage:

```
# Page One {#page_one}

Content
```

When I generate my documentation, I get the expected tree structure. However, when I click `Related Pages`, this is what I get:

[image]

Obviously, I have no benefit from an empty related pages tab. Thus, is there any way to get *rid* of this empty tab? If so, how should I change my Doxyfile?

Answer (score 3):

You have defined the top page as `USE_MDFILE_AS_MAINPAGE` and all other pages are direct or indirect sub-pages of this page.

The display of the `Related Pages` is steered by means of the `DoxygenLayout.xml` (can be generated by means of `doxygen -l`, see also `LAYOUT_FILE`) and in here there is an item `pages`, when setting this item to `no` the `Related Pages` tab is not generated.

Comment: That gets rid of the related pages tab, but now when I open the Tree View, _my_ markdown pages are not visible there. Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQ2x3.png). This suggests that the markdown pages _are_ part of the related pages. If they are, then why aren't they showing up otherwise?

Comment: Looks indeed like some interaction, will have to look a bit deeper into the source code (as it is an extension to the original question).

Comment: Well, I hope you don't mind my inquiring mind! ;-) You did answer my question, but it was under my incorrect assumption that the markdown pages have no relation to the related pages.